# Using the D-statistic from 2-sample KS-tests

Tags: kolmogorov-smirnov-test, two-sample

this my first attempt at applying a 2-sample KS-test. I have 3 sets of data; each comprises of control and treatment values, as follows and plotted in the image:
Set 1: 10,849 values each for control and treated groups; 
Set 2: 8,939 values each for control and treated groups; 
Set 3: 15,680 values each for control and treated groups.
A bit more explanation on the data: All values are log-transformed; sets 1, 2 and 3 are really three different clusters of regions on the genome; and the control or treatment values for the genomic regions in each set are obtained from the same genome-wide signal datasets. Hence the level of signal from a control or treatment set is measured for different regions on the genome (10,849, 8,939 and 15,680 regions).
[image]
Here are the relative frequency distribution curves:
[image]
My goal is to determine if there are any significant differences between the control and treated distributions. I get p<0.0001 for each set, even for Sets 1 and 2, guess due to the large sample sizes. D for each set is mentioned below the respective violin plot. So, I wonder if it is fair, or not, to say anything about the variation between he three sets based on the D statistic. Can I say that even though p-value is small for each set, the difference in D indicates the different "extent" of variability between control and treated for the three sets? Is it not possible to make any such comment (at all, or not) since n is different for the three sets? I am trying to understand if the D-statistic can be used in this manner.

Comment: You have established there *are* differences.  But are they large enough to matter?  If so, what is the nature of the difference?  Q-Q plots can help.